# PHP multiple ^ 2 arrays

Tags: php

> I'm so sorry for this title. I'm really stuck on this, and I don't know how to express in title.

I have this function:

```
public function users($id) {
    $users = array(
                1 => "Leader",
                2 => "General",
                4 => "Marshall",
                8 => "Captain",
                16 => "Master",
                32 => "Member",
                64 => "Vendor",
                128 => "Justin Bieber",
                256 => "Nick Minaj",
                512 => "God"
     );
}
```

So, I want to know how I can return the value inside array keys corresponding to the ID (concatenate).

E.g: If I pass: `$this->users(19)`. Should be return: `Leader, General, Master.`

Thanks!

Comment: it is not clear at all...describe more about what you want

Comment: Not sure, with which logic `$this->users(19)` can return `Leader, General, Master.`. Can you better explain it?

Comment: it seems as though you want to return all strings where the array keys add up to the parameter passed to the function. is that correct?

Comment: For `$this->users(19)` - get keys which sum is 19.

Comment: Yes... If I pass ID 19, will return Leader, General and Master because 1 + 2 + 16 = 19.

Comment: Ah... the special case of the knapsack problem, subset sum problem. OP, google about it to learn the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution could look like this:

```
public function users($id) {
    $users = array(
                1 => "Leader",
                2 => "General",
                4 => "Marshall",
                8 => "Captain",
                16 => "Master",
                32 => "Member",
                64 => "Vendor",
                128 => "Justin Bieber",
                256 => "Nick Minaj",
                512 => "God"
     );

  $out = [];
  $start = $i = max(array_keys($users));
  for( $i=$start; $i>=1; $i /= 2 ) {
   if( $id >= $i ){
     $out[] = $users[$i];
     $id -= $i;
   }
  }

  return implode( ',', array_reverse( $out ) );
}
```

However, I think, that the datastructure should be changed. This way feels clumsy.

Comment: That's I need. Thank you!

Comment: you should make your return function be a bit more dynamic than to always start at 512, something like `$i = max(array_keys($users));` also, your function will return the values in the wrong order, they'll be returned as such: `Master, General, Leader`

Answer (score 1):

you would need to do something like this:

```
public function users($id) {
    $users = array(
                1 => "Leader",
                2 => "General",
                4 => "Marshall",
                8 => "Captain",
                16 => "Master",
                32 => "Member",
                64 => "Vendor",
                128 => "Justin Bieber",
                256 => "Nick Minaj",
                512 => "God"
     );
     $bin = strrev(decbin($id));
     $len = strlen($bin);
     $return = array();
     for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
         if($bin[$i] === '1'){
             $return[] = $users[pow(2, $i)];
         }
     }
     return implode(", ", $return);
}
```